# Строка не равна введенной пользователем строке c++

Tags: строки, c++

```
char **translate_words = new char *[count];
translate_words [0] = new char [3];
translate_words [0] = "yes";
char **user_words = new char *[count];
user_words [0] = new char [3];
cin >> user_words [0];

if (user_words [0] == translate_words [0])
    {
        cout << "Верно";
    }
        else
    {
        cout << "Неверно";
    }
```

Ввожу 'yes', пишет 'Неверно', почему?

Comment: код вида

    translate_words [0] = new char [3];
    translate_words [0] = "yes";

неверный. Вначале выделяете память, потом перетираете ее. как минимум утечка в 3 байта. И это не с++ у Вас, а какой то полу-С. Хотите плюсы - используйте `std::string`. Хотите С выделять память, тогда пишите указанную строку так

    translate_words [0] = strdup("yes");

Answer (score 5):

Потому что вы пытаетесь сравнивать адреса массивов `char`'ов, а не сами массивы. Для сравнения массивов символов по содержимому вам нужна функция [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Постарайтесь понять логику указателей, без этого в C/C++ делать нечего.

Answer (score 5):

Не верно потому что вы сверяете не строки как вы думаете, а тока указатели на эти строки, по этому они и не равны.

Замените ваше условие

```
if (user_words [0] == translate_words [0])
```

на

```
if (strcmp(user_words[0], translate_words[0]) == 0)
```

Так же вы выделяете под строку "yes" массив из 3х элементов, но в С и С++ строки заканчиваются '\0' символом, то есть для строки "yes" нужно 4 символа выделять.

А вообще если вы на С++ работаете то используйте для строк стандартный класс std::string и вместо массива в котором хранятся строки используйте контейнеры стандартные, к примеру std::vector.